# Как правильно писать хранимые процедуры

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqldeveloper

```
CREATE PROCEDURE show @faculty VARCHAR(20) 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tutor
WHERE title LIKE @faculty+'%'
END

    The procedure execution:

EXEC show 'FI'
```

Как переделать этот запрос что бы он работал в SQL Developer?

Comment: Никак, хранимые процедуры в Oracle не могут возвращать набор данных. они могут получить что то в переменных и вывести куда нибудь. могут сделать курсор и вернуть его (правда вы им в SQL developer все равно не воспользуетесь). Но вы можете сделать табличную функцию и она сможет вернуть таблицу https://habrahabr.ru/post/119996/

Comment: А что это и где оно работает?

Answer (score 9):

Что бы правильно написать хранимую процедуру, надо ознакомится с [документацией](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370).
Где её писать, в SQL Developer или на пергаменте, не имеет большого значения.

```
create table tutor as select 1 as id, 'FI bla bla' as title from dual;

create or replace procedure show(prefix varchar2) as
begin 
    for myrow in (select * from tutor where title like prefix || '%') loop
        dbms_output.put_line('row=' || myrow.id || ',' || myrow.title);
    end loop;
end show;
/

exec show('FI');
row=1,FI bla bla
```